TypeScript infer the return type of a function based on the value of one of its parameters
I need the return type of a function to change depending on the value of one of the function's parameters.
The parameter is of type Command as defined below. The goal is for this to be extensible so more commands can be added.
type Command = 'trueOrFalse' | 'logSomething';

There is a function handleCommand(command: Command) => ??? where the return type will change based on the command. However I would like it to be able to infer the return type, so like when you call handleCommand('trueOrFalse') it knows it will return a boolean.
I have this:
type Command = 'trueOrFalse' | 'logSomething'

type CommandHandler = {
    'trueOrFalse': () => boolean;
    'logSomething': () => void;
}

type Handlers = {
    [Key in Command]: () => ReturnType<CommandHandler[K]>;
}

handleCommand<T extends Command>(command: T): ReturnType<CommandHandler[T]> {
    const handlers: Handlers = {
        'trueOrFalse': () => true,
        'logSomething': () => { console.log('Test') }
    }

    const handler = handlers[command] as () => ReturnType<CommandHandler[T]>;

    if (!handler) {
        //error
    }

    return handler();
}

When I call this function however, regardless if I pass 'trueOrFalse' or 'logSomething' the return type is boolean | void. Is it possible to get the function to realize that when 'trueOrFalse' is the argument it should be boolean return type?
I have added a lot of this to resolve type errors within the function like the Handlers type and the casting of handler constant. Now the function itself has no type errors, but the return type is not what I want it to be.
Edit:
OK turns out this issue is related to having an intermediary function that calls handleEvent.
This is the intermediary function.
triggerCommand(command: Command) {
    return this.commandDispatcher.handleCommand(command);
}

Here is what causes a type error
let bool: boolean;
bool = triggerCommand('trueOrFalse'); // boolean | void cannot be assigned to boolean

Thank you. To resolve this had to explicitly state return type of triggerCommand
triggerCommand<T extends Command>(command: Command): ReturnType<CommandHandler[T]>

Sorry I didn't provide this context was not considering this intermediary function as it doesn't do anything. Makes sense why it was not working.

What's the problem? it's working properly: Playground, in fact you don't even need to assert type to handlers[command]

Please [edit] to provide a [mre] where we can clearly see the problem you're seeing when we look at it in our IDEs. Right now it seems like there's no problem at all, as the previous comment shows, and so the question risks being closed as being irreproducible or as needing debugging details.

Sorry I forgot that handleCommand was actually being called through another function. Updated the question.

You simply need to make triggerCommand generic as well.
function triggerCommand<T extends Command>(command: T) {
    return handleCommand(command);
}

let bool: boolean;
bool = triggerCommand('trueOrFalse'); // fine

This allows the implicit return type to be derived from T instead of being all possible return types.
See playground
